# Interchanging expectation and integral for stochastic double integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am trying to show that the expectation of

$\int_{\tau_n}^{\tau_{n+1}}\int_{\tau_n}^{s_2}dWs_1ds_2$

is 0. Is it possible to take the expectation inside the time integral, so that

$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_{\tau_n}^{\tau_{n+1}}\int_{\tau_n}^{s_2}dWs_1ds_2\bigg] = \int_{\tau_n}^{\tau_{n+1}}\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_{\tau_n}^{s_2}dWs_1\bigg]ds_2 = \int_{\tau_n}^{\tau_{n+1}}\mathbb{E}\bigg[W_{s_2}-W_{\tau_n}\bigg]ds_2 = 0$

since the expectation of the Brownian motion increments are $N(0,s_2-\tau_n)$? I feel that Fubini's theorem might come into play somewhere, but I do not know if Fubini's theorem applies to Brownian motions. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are $\tau_n$ stopping times (i.e. random) or deterministic times?

Comment: My understanding is that they are deterministic, just incremental times in a partition

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an application of the Fubini theorem: Take the probability space:
$$(\Omega \times [t_1, t_2], \mathbb{P}_W \otimes \lambda)$$
where $\mathbb{P}_W $ is the Wiener measure (so implicitly $\Omega = C[0, T]$) and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Now take the map $f(\omega, s) =\omega(s)= W_s.$ Then an application of Fubini's theorem on this map will give you the required result.

Note that for stopping times the result will not be true in general.